# Change Play console default currency

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, google-play-console, in-app-subscription

I have created a google play account with a merchant profile in the UK. So, the default currency for in-app subscription is in GBP.

When I created a subscription, it shows info message

"List includes countries where users make payments using local currency. In the 61 other countries where you distribute your app, your price in GBP will be used instead."

My requirement is to use the price in USD in the other 61 countries mentioned in the info.

One of the solutions found is a Merchant account with a US address. I am not able to do it.

So, I want to know what would be the default currency if I make a merchant account in the other 61 countries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution is Merchant address with US Address.

The Merchant account creation in other 61 countries is not supported.